# LXPanel applets cannot be added to the status bar

Tags: raspbian, lxde

I seem to have lost "Wireless & Wired Network" and "Bluetooth" applets for `lxpanel` after a Buster->Bullseye upgrade. The relevant packages (`lxplug-network` and `lxplug-bluetooth`) appears to be installed:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dpkg -l | grep lxpanel
ii  lxpanel                                0.10.1-2                         armhf        LXDE panel
ii  lxpanel-data                           0.10.1-2                         all          LXDE panel (data files)
ii  lxplug-bluetooth                       0.21                             armhf        Bluetooth plugin for lxpanel
ii  lxplug-cputemp                         0.6                              armhf        CPU temperature plugin for lxpanel
ii  lxplug-ejecter                         0.15                             armhf        Ejecter plugin for lxpanel
ii  lxplug-magnifier                       0.6                              armhf        Magnifier plugin for lxpanel
ii  lxplug-network                         0.24                             armhf        Network plugin for lxpanel
ii  lxplug-ptbatt                          0.14                             armhf        Battery monitor plugin for lxpanel
ii  lxplug-volumepulse                     0.5                              armhf        PulseAudio controller plugin for lxpanel
```

However, when I click on "Add / Remove Panel Items" menu, I don't see them in the list.

The relevant services (`dhcpcd` and `bluetooth`) are up and running:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-11-08 22:16:08 CET; 10h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 584 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
        CPU: 106ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─584 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ service dhcpcd status
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-11-08 22:16:05 CET; 10h ago
    Process: 375 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -b (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 425 (dhcpcd)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
        CPU: 16.272s
     CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
             ├─425 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -b
             └─588 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 51:81:EA:67:17:47 51-81-EA-67-17-47
[CHG] Device 51:81:EA:67:17:47 RSSI: -45
[CHG] Device 51:81:EA:67:17:47 RSSI: -62
```

Did I install the wrong packages, or is there a configuration for `lxpanel` that I need to apply?