# connman unable to connect to wifi: No carrier

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

This is on a system upgraded from Buster to Bullseye. Ethernet works fine, but WiFi cannot scan for available networks with "No carrier" error message:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ connmanctl enable wifi
Error wifi: Already enabled
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ connmanctl scan wifi
Error /net/connman/technology/wifi: No carrier
```

I can see that `wlan0` is there, not blocked by `rfkill` and `wpa_supplicant` is running.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status 579
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-11-19 16:40:15 CET; 24h ago
    Process: 429 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -b (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 489 (dhcpcd)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
        CPU: 34.626s
     CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
             ├─489 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -b
             └─579 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
```

Is there anything else I should check? Or is `connmanctl` not supposed to work on Bullseye?

@Milliways, `connman` appears to be installed as a dependency of `lxde`, which is what I have for desktop on the Pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-cache --installed rdepends connman-gtk
connman-gtk
Reverse Depends:
 |lxde
```

Comment: Did you install connman yourself? I have never used it, but the instructions say to disable other networking systems. You have the normal Raspberry Pi OS dhcpcd client running.

Comment: Did you see [this Q&A](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=221772) in the Arch forum?

Comment: @Milliways I didn't install it myself. Looking at [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/133325/33476) made me think this is now the default GUI network manager in Raspbian. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Seamus I sure did. The `pi` user is not in `wheel` and `network` groups, but I assumed it's arch-spesific

Comment: There have been a few red herrings recently about `connman`. I have done updates & fresh install of Bullseye & still have `dhcpcd`.  Neither has connman. I did ask the author of that post, but got no sensible answer. I have seen nothing from RPT suggesting such a change, so I can't explain. The same version was in Buster repositories, and a slightly earlier version in Stretch. If you didn't install it (maybe on the image you updated) it would be interesting to examine the logs. If there was any change in NM I would expect `systemd-networkd`.

Comment: @Milliways it seems to be a dependency of lxde, according to `apt-cache --installed rdepends connman-gtk`. What do you have for NM GUI?

Comment: I notice that `lxde` (which is standard desktop environment for PI) **Recommends: connman-gtk**, which presumably installs connman, so maybe it is a result of installing recommended packages. however it got there connman is incompatible with dhcpcd. If you don't want it I would just delete connman. I note Simon Long's comment that he is the only person supporting lxde.

Comment: @Milliways Do you happen to know which GUI is compatible? Is it `lxplug-network`, and if so, could you help me figure out what am I [missing](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/133138/33476) with it?

Comment: `The pi user is not in wheel and network groups`... Yeah, those groups don't exist in Debian, but they have *equivalents*: `wheel` ~ `sudo`, `network` ~ `netdev`. I wondered if group memberships were changed during the upgrade? Anyway - from the discussion here, your [other question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/133138/33476), and [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133318/how-to-disable-the-dynamic-ip-address-after-assigning-a-static-ip-in-bullseye) this seems rather a significant issue!

Comment: @Seamus No, my `pi` user is still in `sudo` and `netdev` groups, as it was before the update. It's probably a dist-upgrade issue, but I'm essentially OK with command line and don't want to waste another day on either rolling back a buster backup and re-doing the upgrade, or making a fresh install and then going through my bash history and /etc folder for all the changes I have made to my system.

Answer (score 3):

I would just delete connman - from similar posts the dhcpcd plugin (I would have to search to find its name) appears to be installed.

Its normal operation depends on the dhcpcd service (which appears to be running) but dhcpcd disables itself and its wpa supplicant plug-in  if another DHCP client is active.

I will investigate later if this doesn't resolve your issue.

I would use CLI to see what IP have been allocated.

---

See https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/another-raspbian-desktop-user-interface-update/

I think you want the dhcpcd-ui package

```
apt search dhcpcd-ui
lxplug-network/stable,now 0.29 armhf [installed,automatic]
  Network plugin for lxpanel
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed `connman` since it apparently got installed by mistake during the `dist-upgrade`. I'm still looking for a GUI to manage the network connections, but now I know it's not going to be connman.